# Return type in findById method, control could not be found by id

Tags: vba, ms-access, sap-gui

I'm writing a VBA script that read some values from SAP GUI (transaction code `ME23N`).

I'm using `findById` method to read some values but I don't know if the object exists or not.

```
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/sub/.......).Text
```

I'd like to know what `findById` method returns if the provided id does not exists. Knowing that I can handle this situation and avoid runtime message:

> The control could not be found by id

Is there a public SAP documentation where I can find some information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have to add a reference for a SAP library/DLL? If so, then try using F2 to look at methods etc.

Comment: No I haven't. Where can I find them? Is there a way to check if an element exists given its id?

Comment: Open the VBA code window (Alt+F11), then press F2 to see the Object Browser. Type in the value you want to search for and click the 'Search' icon.  Maybe you will find something... you also can search by Library ... but if you didn't add a library for SAP... maybe no luck.

Answer (score -1):

Is this something that youare asking ? This is whati use .....

' bottom left where is displays the errors or message saying you dont have access to the transaction

On Error Resume Next
session.findById("wnd[0]/.....SetFocus 'or .Text

If session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text = "The control could not be found by id." Then
 Debug.Print "transaction not found."

session.findById("wnd[0]").Close ' closing SAP Window \ Program.
 session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press ' press the yes \ok button to close SAP
 Exit Sub
End If

Comment: This answer is poorly formatted and the code is not even correct syntax.